# Debian 8 (Jessie) Wlan0 not detected by ifconfig, iwconfig, network-manager, etc

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I just installed [BunsenLabs](http://bunsenlabs.org) (Debain 8 based) on a Dell Latitude 3470 laptop, and wlan0 is not detected (wasn't during install either).
`ifconfig` doesn't detect it, neither `iwconfig`, neither `network-manager`, etc, etc.

It is *sort of* detected, as both `rfkill list all` and `lspci` picks it up, but it doesn't seem to be picked up by anything else.

I have been trying to solve this for over a day, but nothing seems to work...
Please bear with me, as I don't know much about how this works :/

Outputs of commands:

- `ifconfig -a`: http://pastebin.com/2yXywJa6
- `iwconfig`: http://pastebin.com/wL2PsFwh
- `rfkill list all`: http://pastebin.com/QzUFYW20 (detects it, not blocked)
- `lspci`: http://pastebin.com/Yrt70yig (detects it)
- `dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/c6yYxK73
- `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`: http://pastebin.com/XNHQ7a2i

If there is anything else you need output from, then tell me.